# " TypeError: _Fire.default.shared.addPost is not a function "'Fire.default.shared.addPost' is undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have been getting this error:
TypeError: _Fire.default.shared.addPost is not a function.'Fire.default.shared.addPost' is undefined
I will be glad if anyone can help

```
 handlePost = () => {
Fire.shared
  .addPost({
    text: this.state.text.trim(),
    localUri: this.state.image,
  })
  .then((ref) => {
    this.setState({ text: "", image: null });
    this.props.navigation.goBack();
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    alert(error.message);
  });
```

};

Comment: Could you provide us with relevant code (code that could be a possible reason for this error)? For example, the code that fires the function `_Fire.default.shared.addPost`.

Comment: alright sir i will post the code

Comment: i have shared the code sir

Answer (score 0):

Providing the specific code snippet would be better for understanding.

If you are using the react class component, you may bind the function inside the constructor.

```
constructor(props) 
{
  super(props);
  this.state = {};
  this.addPost= this.addPost.bind(this);
}
```

If you have created reference of child component inside parent and trying to access a function of the child from the parent, then you probably have used a lot of references before. React does not support more than 4 references (approximately).

Probably the `_Fire.default.shared.addPost` function takes arguments and you are not passing necessary and sufficient arguments.

Also, it's possible that you are accessing a function through props. Where in the main component, either the function does not exist, or you have not bound the function or you're not passing necessary arguments while calling props from the child.

**PS:** These are four different scenarios and the possible solutions for each.